# What is causing this kernel panic?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, kernel-panic

```
nterval Since Last Panic Report:  835635 sec
Panics Since Last Report:          3
Anonymous UUID:                    FE016DAD-F74D-CFED-FEBF-38D3994B54B5

Fri Jan 11 19:09:31 2013
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80228b7bd5): Kernel trap at 0xffffff80baddecaf, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0xffffff80baddecaf, CR3: 0x000000002513e000, CR4: 0x00000000000606e0
RAX: 0xffffff80357d6e00, RBX: 0xffffff7fa2f18790, RCX: 0x0000000000000001, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff8113d2be48, RBP: 0xffffff8113d2be80, RSI: 0xffffff803687ecc0, RDI: 0xffffff80357d6e00
R8:  0x00000000000007d0, R9:  0x0000000000000000, R10: 0x00000000ffffffff, R11: 0xffffff8022e7de88
R12: 0xffffff803687ea00, R13: 0xffffff80367b7c00, R14: 0x0000000036706200, R15: 0x0000000000000001
RFL: 0x0000000000010246, RIP: 0xffffff80baddecaf, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff80baddecaf, Error code: 0x0000000000000010, Fault CPU: 0x0

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8113d2bae0 : 0xffffff802281d626 
0xffffff8113d2bb50 : 0xffffff80228b7bd5 
0xffffff8113d2bd20 : 0xffffff80228ce4ed 
0xffffff8113d2bd40 : 0xffffff80baddecaf 
0xffffff8113d2be80 : 0xffffff7fa2f05884 
0xffffff8113d2bf20 : 0xffffff8022c49e4a 
0xffffff8113d2bf60 : 0xffffff802283dcde 
0xffffff8113d2bfb0 : 0xffffff80228b26b7 
     Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
        com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.4d2)[AB9DA44C-0632-35D7-94FE-6D18C4C7ABFA]@0xffffff7fa2f03000->0xffffff7fa2f0ffff
           dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[A35915E8-C1B0-3C0F-81DF-5515BC9002FC]@0xffffff7fa2efa000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
12C60

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 12.2.0: Sat Aug 25 00:48:52 PDT 2012; root:xnu-2050.18.24~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 69A5853F-375A-3EF4-9247-478FD0247333
Kernel slide:     0x0000000022600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8022800000
System model name: MacBookPro8,3 (Mac-942459F5819B171B)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 3816460790282
last loaded kext at 33635384604: com.apple.filesystems.afpfs    10.0 (addr 0xffffff7fa4ca8000, size 348160)
last unloaded kext at 425117387768: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   5.2.5 (addr 0xffffff7fa320c000, size 65536)
loaded kexts:
com.jft.driver.PdaNetDrv    1.0.64
com.displaylink.driver.DisplayLinkDriver    1.8
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 10.0
com.apple.nke.asp_tcp   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelProfile  97
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.filesystems.ntfs  3.10
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    122
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriver  4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothA2DPAudioDriver 4.0.9f33
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.12.69
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport  4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.2d0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.10
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.33
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.AMDRadeonAccelerator  1.0.0
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.ApplePolicyControl 3.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD3000Graphics   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSNBGraphicsFB    8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.2.11
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.2d6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  235.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 235.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  320.15
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 34
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    5.2.5
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.2.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   602.15.22
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.2.5b3
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   5.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 196.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.6
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   4.0.39
com.apple.security.quarantine   2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   196.0.0
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileTimestampAction    97
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileThreadInfoAction   97
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileRegisterStateAction    97
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileReadCounterAction  97
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileKEventAction   97
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileCallstackAction    97
com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily  97
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.9fc10
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.6
com.apple.iokit.AppleBluetoothHCIControllerUSBTransport 4.0.9f33
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.2.0d16
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.10d0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   86.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.3.1f2
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.3.1f2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.10d0
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily 19.0.26
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.0.9f33
com.apple.kext.AMD6000Controller    8.0.0
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   8.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.5
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.4d2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    1.8.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 1.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.5.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 235.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  5.2.5
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    274.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  5.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    1.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 2.1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 5.2.5
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   500.15
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.2b1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 5.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.6.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.8.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  220
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 344
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  28.21
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro8,3, BootROM MBP81.0047.B27, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.3 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 1.70f5
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 3000, Intel HD Graphics 3000, Built-In, 512 MB
Graphics: AMD Radeon HD 6750M, AMD Radeon HD 6750M, PCIe, 1024 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393930353432382D3034372E4130304C4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x0198, 0x393930353432382D3034372E4130304C4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xD6), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.81.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.9f33 10885, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet Adaptor (en3), Ethernet, en3
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: M4-CT128M4SSD2, 128.04 GB
Serial ATA Device: WDC WD7500BPKT-00PK4T0, 750.16 GB
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfa100000 / 3
USB Device: ExpCard Adpt, 0x0781  (SanDisk Corporation), 0xb6d0, 0xfa140000 / 6
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad, apple_vendor_id, 0x0245, 0xfa120000 / 5
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.), 0x4500, 0xfa110000 / 4
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x821a, 0xfa113000 / 7
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in), apple_vendor_id, 0x8509, 0xfa200000 / 2
USB Device: hub_device, 0x0424  (SMSC), 0x2514, 0xfd100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8242, 0xfd110000 / 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Kernel panics are all but inevitably caused by either hardware problems or rogue kernel extensions--specifically drivers. Panic reports list all the loaded and unloaded extensions in the expectation that the culprit is a non-Apple driver.

In your case, there are two: one for PdaNet and one for DisplayLink. A web search revealed no complaints about the DisplayLink driver's behavior, but the same could not be said for the one from PDANet; it shows up in a large number of KP reports.

I downloaded the PDANet desktop application (iPhone model, version 1.0.64). Glancing through an ASCII dump of the com.jft.driver.PdaNetDrv extension discloses it was built using a 10.6 SDK, so it's quite possible, if not likely, the driver is incompatible with Mountain Lion.

I suggest uninstalling the PDANet application and the driver extension. You should have gotten an uninstall shell script with the installation package which will remove the driver; if not, contact June Fabrics and request one. Simply removing the application will not do the job.

If the panics stop occurring, let a few days go by before you consider the problem solved. It could just be a coincidence, and if another one occurs, you would then almost certainly be looking at a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put in the first Mac OS install disk and reboot holding the D key down. This will cause Hardware test to run. It will test all the hardware. This panic looks like a ram issue. All the numbers are memory address. Most likely you have a ram stick that went bad.